# Why CSMA/CD and CSMA/CA are classified as broadcast based?

Tags: networking

In CSMA/CD and CSMA/CA , why the Communication mode for these two access methods are classified as Broadcast based ?

For CSMA/CA a Node sends a broadcast message to notify the other nodes on the network that it wants to send .

But for CSMA/CD why it is Broadcast Based ? is it because the Jamming signal ?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are broadcast mechanisms because they are used on broadcast media. On a broadcast medium, all end stations hear all transmissions. CSMA CA or CD are used to prevent two stations from transmitting at the same time.
Ethernet and 802.11 ( Wi-fi) are two examples of broadcast media.

Comment: You should add "... *early* Ethernet and 802.11 are two examples". Ethernet has long ceased to be used with broadcast media (coax or repeated TP/fiber), all modern variants use collision-free point-to-point signaling